# "translating" { ...props } in JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I am building a package with reusable components, that I want to publish to NPM.

`.babelrc`

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react"]
}
```

`.eslintrc`

```
{
  root: true,
  parser: 'babel-eslint',
  plugins: [/*'import', */'jsx-a11y', 'react'],
env: {
    browser: true,
    commonjs: true,
    es6: true,
    jest: true,
    node: true
  },
parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 6,
    sourceType: 'module',
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true,
      generators: true,
      experimentalObjectRestSpread: true
    }
  },
settings: {
    'import/ignore': [
      'node_modules',
      '\\.(json|css|jpg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm)$',
    ],
    'import/extensions': ['.js'],
    'import/resolver': {
      node: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.json']
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`package.json`

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.4.2"
  }
}
```

I would like to be able to "unpack" a JS object like so: `var x = {...this.props}` but when running my build script it gets stuck on the `...this.props` part.

What do I need to translate this syntax?

Comment: I guess `stage-2` preset of Babel.

Comment: Take a look at `babel-preset-env`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider using the [transform object rest spread plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread.html). See how to add it to your Babel config in the [usage](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-preset-env) section. You can add it to your `.babelrc` like so:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react"],
  "plugins": ["transform-object-rest-spread"]
}
```

The "stage" presets have been [deprecated](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/v7-migration#stage-preset-deprecations-https-githubcom-babel-babel-issues-7770) in the current Babel release.

While `babel-preset-env` *may* also provide this capability, it's not targeted to what you need in the question you're asking – it's got a broader use case although I agree you should at least consider it. Learn more about it [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-preset-env).